# HTML Input button positioned in div

Tags: java, html, input, wicket

I'm still getting a RuntimeException while rendering my page, and I don't understand the reason. It tells that the closing `</div>` is missing, but it is already there. What could be the solution for this exception?

Stracktrace:

**Unexpected RuntimeException**:

org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupException: Expected close tag for '`<div class="device-nr" wicket:id="sampleHeader">`' Possible attempt to embed component(s) '`<input wicket:id="saveButton" type="submit" value="Save"/>`' in the body of this component which discards its body
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupStream.throwMarkupException(MarkupStream.java:526)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.replaceComponentTagBody(Component.java:4045) 
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label.onComponentTagBody(Label.java:131)

and here is my html code:

```
<wicket:extend>
    <form class = sample-form wicket:id="sample_form">
        <div class="device-nr" wicket:id="sampleHeader">
            <input wicket:id="saveButton" type="submit" value="Save"/>
        </div>
        <wicket:child />
        <!-- display error here -->
        <div class= "feedback" wicket:id="feedback"></div>
        <div class="sample_details" wicket:id="sample_details"></div>
    </form>
</wicket:extend>
```

Here is my Java-Code:

```
this.form = new Form<T>("sample_form", compound);
    form.add(new Button("saveButton") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5878291170139126213L;

        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {
            T s = form.getModelObject();
            logger.info(s.toString());

        }
    });
    form.add(new Label("sampleHeader", provideSampleHeader()));
    form.add(provideSamplePanel());
    form.add(new FeedbackPanel("feedback"));
    add(form);
```

thankyou for you help!

Comment: OK, so... where's the stacktrace?

Comment: it's pretty long.. I'll try to paste a little part of it.

Comment: any idea, what can I do to get rid of this exceptio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a Label on the div-tag. A Label overrides any markup that's inside it's tag so removing the input tag you're using to anchor your Button.

To get rid of this you'll need another tag (most likely a wicket:container as it only renders it's contents) for your Label.

Something like

```
<wicket:extend>
    <form class = sample-form wicket:id="sample_form">
        <div class="device-nr"> <wicket:container wicket:id="sampleHeader" />
            <input wicket:id="saveButton" type="submit" value="Save"/>
        </div>
        <wicket:child />
        <!-- display error here -->
        <div class= "feedback" wicket:id="feedback"></div>
        <div class="sample_details" wicket:id="sample_details"></div>
    </form>
</wicket:extend>
```

I can't test it right now as I don't have a wicket installation here to try it...